# SQL CMD :setvar from file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I am using a PostDeploy script in a SQL Server project in Visual Studio.
Is there a way I could read the content of a file (JSON) from the project as a variable into this script?

I know I can use :r to read SQL scripts into the post deployment script, but I'd need something similar with JSON.

Comment: You could probably do it with some sort of OPENJSON type query, but I haven't really tried that.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSchott, I tried OPENJSON, but the issue with that is that the database is in Azure, while my JSON file is in my local project, so Azure cannot access that. Could work if the file was in cloud, though.

Comment: That solution you came up with was about what I was going to suggest. Need something that can be consumed from a known location on the build box. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a PowerShell script that feeds the JSON into a SQL variable in a file which is then referenced by the post deploy script.

I run this script in the Post-build event of the Visual Studio project.

```
$sqlScriptPath = ".\Scripts\SetJsonVariables.sql";
$sql = "DECLARE @EtlConfigDev NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@@@EtlConfigDev'"
$sql = $sql.replace("@@@EtlConfigDev", (Get-Content ".\Json\EtlConfigDev.json" -replace "'", "''"))
$sql | Set-Content -Path $sqlScriptPath
```